# Ricci Tensor and Einstein Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

What can we say about an hypersurface Einstein manifolds on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ when $n\geq 3$ ?

The manifolds is Einstein so Ricci tensor is a multiply of the metric $g$ on manifold:

$Ric=\lambda g$ where $\lambda\in C^\infty(M)$

If $S$ is the scalar curvature of $M$ then the relationship between $S$ and $\lambda$ is

$\lambda=\frac{S}{n}$

Because the scalar curvature of $M$ is the trace of Ricci tensor.

So using the condition that $n\geq 3$ and using  a contraction of the second Bianchi Identity we have that the scalar curvature of $M$ is costant so $\lambda$ is costant.

Another condition that we have is that $M$ is an hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so we can use also the Codazzi-Mainardi Equation ti get some equation between the mean curvature $H$ of $M$, the metric $g$ and the second fondamental formula of $M$.
What can other we say about $M$, it is possible classify it?

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bang_Yen_Chen/publication/271505602_Einstein_manifolds_as_affine_hypersurfaces/links/55280e650cf29b22c9ba7744/Einstein-manifolds-as-affine-hypersurfaces.pdf

Comment: What I must search in this book? There are a lot of sections